# There Is no zoomIn() method in flot

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I searched out the whole internet, but I couldn't find if there exists a zoomIn() method for flot chart or not just like the zoomOut() method which works really fine.

I need a zoomIn() method for the chart, please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flot's [navigate plugin](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.navigate.js) provides the `zoomOut()` and `zoom()` method (the `zoom()` method zooms in). The `zoom()` method is pretty straightforward to use:

```
// zoom 200% in on the pixel (10, 20)
plot.zoom({ amount: 2, center: { left: 10, top: 20 } });
```

Comment: Oh it provides zoom() instead of zoomIn() hahaha,,

Thank you , that's what I've been looking for ::)

Comment: @TheSuperKat don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem!

Comment: Sorry , Im new,, so I just did,, Thank you